# Switch between a headed and headless server when integration testing with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, webrat

Let's say I have web-rat and selenium installed. How do I test my rails app quickly with web-rat (using capybara) , and then, do one final integration test with selenium?

Comment: What are you using to kick the webrat tests off? Could you write a shell script to run the webrat tests and then kick off your selenium tests?

Comment: Good point I'm using capybara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `spec/spec_helper.rb`

Add this line:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium # This is capybara's default server anyway!
```

Now simply change the symbol to reference whichever server you want. 
E.g.

To use webkit:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
```

Or to use Poltergesit:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
```